# How to join user profile to user topics in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

In Django 1.7, I am trying to make a user panel in which userprofile info (like avatar, country, etc.) are to be displayed along with their topics. Here is the view:

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Listing of posts in a thread."""
    posts = Post.objects.select_related('creator') \
        .filter(topic=topic_id).order_by("created")
    posts = mk_paginator(request, posts, DJANGO_SIMPLE_FORUM_REPLIES_PER_PAGE)
    topic = Topic.objects.get(pk=topic_id)
    topic.visits += 1
    topic.save()

    return render_to_response("myforum/topic.html", add_csrf(request, posts=posts, pk=topic_id,
        topic=topic), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The Topic model is:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    visits = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

And the UserProfile model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices= COUTNRY_CHOICES, blank=True)
    avatar = ImageWithThumbsField(), upload_to='images', sizes=((32,32),(150,150),(200,200)), blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
```

However, when in topic.html I try to capture the userprofile info in template, e.g.

```
{{topic.creator.userprofile.name}}
```

or

```
{{topic.creator.userprofile.city}}
```

nothing is displayed. This happens for all fields that I try to fetch from UserProfile model, despite the fact that in the database the userprofile row for the user is not empty and I can get fields in other views.

I have been stuck on this for days so really appreciate your help.

Update: here is add_csrf, in case it might be relevant

```
def add_csrf(request, ** kwargs):
    d = dict(user=request.user, ** kwargs)
    d.update(csrf(request))
    return d
```

Comment: is "COUTNRY_CHOICES" supposed to be "COUNTRY_CHOICES"?

Comment: @MattGiltaji, no. It is an irrelevant typo. As I said this happens for all fields that I try to fetch from UserProfile model. Just updated question to remove this distraction.

Comment: @Filly How to access model from shell? I can see the userprofile rows in mysql shell though, but in django shell, I get `NameError: name 'User' is not defined`

Comment: @Filly, yes I can access the user from shell.

Comment: What is your ``add_csrf()`` function?

Comment: @Tony, I added the function to my question.

Comment: And you're absolutely sure that the `creator` field of the topic in question is not empty? As the field is `null=True`. In addition, it's typically a bad idea to use the pk as an identifier, as it's just an "arbitrary" number. Something that is under your control and more semantic would be better.

Comment: @Johndt6 yes the field is not empty. I can access it in the template using `{{ topic.creator }}`

Comment: What happens when you try an just have `{{topic.creator}}` or `{{topic.creator.userprofile}}` in the template? Does anything show then?

Comment: Guys, I have to applogize. The problem turned out to be that   `username = models.OneToOneField(User)` was not actually imposed in table relationships. I realized this just after I `desc` userprofile_userprofile and found no unique key there. After removing migrations folder from the app and redoing migrations the problem solved.